# Meanwell vs generic power supply

Tags: power-supply, diy

I am currently planning out a custom 3D printer build which will run on a 24V 600W power supply.  I have specked out for a $90 MeanWell supply from [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Mean-Well-SE-600-24-AC-DC-Power-Supply-Single-OUT-24V-25A-600W-US-Authorized-NEW/122049783261?hash=item1c6abbe5dd:g:bRMAAOSw0vBUlODi), but I've noticed similar generic power for only $50.

I was wondering if there are any *real* advantages to spending the extra $40 on a name brand power supply....

Comment: Read the datasheet of each supply, if the cheaper supply meets your requirements, do it. Every line on the spec sheet is an opportunity for a *real* advantage of the one supply over the other. Whether the advantage applies to you depends on if you need it.

Comment: The advantages might not be obvious from the datasheet. My guess is that a supply from a reputable brand often has better **safety features** like better mains isolation and a proper fuse to protect against fire if something breaks. Only opening and comparing these supplies side-by-side and some relevant experience will reveal if one supply is better than the other. A 600 W PSU for $50 does sound a bit too cheap to me though.

Comment: If I were building up a 3D printer (and I have built 2), I would realize that there is significant time investment both in the initial work needed to get everything working as well as I can achieve (and there is a lot there, already) as well as the time when using the device afterwards. If you can afford a good 3D printer at all, then you can afford to use components from reputable sources. The MeanWell doesn't sound like a gold-plated price. But reasonable. I'd probably go that direction, if otherwise ignorant about specs. Call MeanWell up. Ask them about it. See if they make sense to you.

Comment: The difference is the cheap power supply is much more likely to blow up prematurely because of cheap undersized components inside. E.g 85°C Al-caps instead of 105°C ones.

Comment: (1) It's unlikely that one of us EE.SE denizens works for a power supply manufacturer and is willing to share the quality procedures (or lack thereof).  We don't really know their exact component sourcing and testing practices.  As a result, this question is opinion-based.  (2) In my opinion it's probably okay to use a generic power supply for a one-off 3D printer for your own in-house use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwell (assuming they are actually made by Meanwell and not counterfeits) are quality controlled by reputable company. They will meet FCC and UL/CSA safety standards and won't likely burn up or electrocute you without good reason. They may have more likelyhood of failing such a way that would be catastrophic for connected equipment.

If you buy something from a less reputable company you are taking a risk, and I certainly would take the data sheet claims with a grain of salt when you are dealing with unknowns.

Be sure that the Meanwell supply is actually an original. You don't want to pay a premium for junk with fake safety markings. And there is a lot of such stuff out there. eBay is not exactly a pathway for franchised distributors in most cases, nor is Aliexpress. You might have slightly better chance of getting your money back with eBay.